# Php form repeater post

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to make a form using form repeater. As a result of my efforts somehow I could not register in the database.

html code:

```
<div class="m-portlet__body" id="myRadioGroup">
    <div id="m_repeater_1">
        <div class="form-group  m-form__group row" id="m_repeater_1">
            <div data-repeater-list="" class="col-md-12">
                <div data-repeater-item class="form-group m-form__group row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-12 m-form__group-sub">
                        <label class="form-control-label">Car plate</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="plate" placeholder="34 LAA 34" maxlength="10">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button data-repeater-delete="" class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="la la-trash-o"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="m-form__group form-group row" style="padding-left: 48px; margin-top: -2rem;">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div data-repeater-create="" class="btn btn btn-sm btn-brand m-btn m-btn--icon m-btn--wide">
                        <span>
                            <i class="la la-plus"></i>
                            <span>add plate</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

chrome looks like this in developer tools:
[image]
How should my database registration file be?

```
$plate = $_POST['plate'];

$sql = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO orders (plate) VALUES (?)');
$save = $sql->execute(array(
    $plate,
));
```

Comment: Why do you vote minus?

Comment: You seem to be wanting to insert an multi-dimensional array but not treating it as such. There's also no "jquery" here or the method used.

Comment: What's a "repeater"?  Why is the HTML in your screenshot different from the HTML code you've written?  How are you sending your data to the server?

Comment: You're also not doing array inputs properly. It's name[key][]

Comment: I'm using jquery form repeater. @David

Comment: @bhdrnzl: Not in the code shown in the question you're not.  Please create a Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: *"Why do you vote minus?"* - Because your question is unclear and doesn't contain relevant code and were asked a few questions asking for clarification but you failed to update your question to contain it. Edit: The more time you (make us) wait, the more time it takes for you to get a possible solution.

Comment: https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater
I want to send the duplicate form to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the html code, input name should be `plate[1]`. One possible cause is that you have `id="m_repeater_1"` declared twice. Make sure you are setting the template correctly first, and then you can search in all post data by using `print_r($_POST);` (with your current code no POST is being sent).

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Amount" name="repeat[0][amount]" class="form-control">

public function add()
{
    $locations = $_POST['repeat'];
    foreach ($locations as $key => $subValue) {

    echo $subValue['amount'];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain, why this code is an answer for the question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer